# How do you get a Google Chart to redraw based on data you pass to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

The bulk of the examples I've found showing Google Charts have simple little arrays...

I need to pull an array from my server.

I can get a pie chart to draw, but it doesn't update.

Here is my attempt to get a flexible, redrawing pie chart:

At the top of my javascript, but before document.ready:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

My drawChart function:

```
function drawChart(arrFeedbackResult3) {
  console.log('Draw a fucking chart ... ') + console.log(arrFeedbackResult3);

  var chart_data = new google.visualization.DataTable(arrFeedbackResult3);
  var options = {
    title: 'Comments by Group',
    sliceVisibilityThreshold: 1/20, // Only > 5% will be shown.
    width: 400,
    height: 400
  };

  chart = new
  google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('groupPieChartDiv'));
  chart.draw(chart_data, options);
  // chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('groupPieChartDiv'));
  // chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

And the function that, after a button is clicked, passes fresh data to drawChart:

```
function setupFeedback3(arrFeedbackResult3){    //  Create Group summary Graphs

  console.log('Groups summary from DB: ') + console.log(arrFeedbackResult3);

  drawChart(arrFeedbackResult3);
}   //  END setupFeedback3
```

I get a "table has no columns" message on my page with the above code.

The array, arrFeedbackResult3, is formatted correctly and does render a chart when I change the code but end up without the ability to refresh.

Any help appreciated. I think I'm just missing the basic flow of using Google Charts...and how/where the callback should be used.

---

Updating with my next attempt after a very generous and detailed reply.

My js is in a separate file from the html. I cannot get the passing of an array via callback to work. I get "not a constructor" errors or "not a function." I think because adding a parenthetical value breaks the code.

I also don't understand the comment about document.ready in the answer...I have kept document.ready in order to load all my other functions.

Right after document.ready I have:

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart'],
  callback: drawChart
});
```

Then, after my db POST to get data, I call:

```
function setupFeedback3(result){    //  Create Group summary Graphs
  arrFeedbackResult3 = result;    //Store in global variable for access by chart
  drawChart();
}   //  END setupFeedback3
```

arrFeedbackResult3 is a GLOBAL variable - only way I could get the data to the draw chart function.

Then:

```
function drawChart() {
  console.log('Draw a chart ... ') + console.log(arrFeedbackResult3);

  // var chart_data = new google.visualization.DataTable(arrFeedbackResult3);
  var chart_data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrFeedbackResult3);

  var options = {
    title: 'Comments by Group',
    sliceVisibilityThreshold: 1/20,
    width: 400,
    height: 400
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('groupPieChartDiv'));
  chart.draw(chart_data, options);
}
```

This is working, and the chart does update as you feed different data, but it seems a shoddy state of affairs. One specific example of passing data, vs. a stupid simple example or using AJAX inside the function, would have been really helpful.

Comment: Not really to do with the question, but when using console.log you can write a string with the output as opposed to having two separate calls: console.log("Hello world!", myOutput);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first,**  recommend *not using* `jsapi` to load the library.

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic `loader.js` from now on.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

this will *only* change the `load` statement...

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages:['corechart']});
```

---

**next,** the callback can be added to the load statement...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart'],
  callback: drawChart
});
```

or you can use the promise it returns...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(drawChart);
```

also, the load statement will wait until the document is ready by default,
so it can be used in place of --> `$(document).ready`

---

**finally,** when creating a data table,
the argument for the constructor should be JSON, not a simple array
see [Format of the Constructor's JavaScript Literal data Parameter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam),
for the specific JSON format

if you want to create a data table from a simple array,
use [static method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#assortedmethods) --> `arrayToDataTable`

---

recommend setup similar to following...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  // get data
  drawChart(arrayData);
});

function drawChart(arrayData) {
  var chart_data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

  var options = {
    title: 'Comments by Group',
    sliceVisibilityThreshold: 1/20,
    width: 400,
    height: 400
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('groupPieChartDiv'));
  chart.draw(chart_data, options);
}

function setupFeedback(arrayData) {
  // get data
  drawChart(arrayData);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

you can use the promise the load statement returns as the callback **and** the document ready
just move the code as shown below...

then you can load your ajax call to get the data

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {

  // move code from document ready here

  // get data
  getData();

});

function getData() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: sourceURL,
    success: setupFeedback
  });
}

function setupFeedback(result) {
  // you could draw the chart here
  // just move the code from drawChart

  // or pass the data along to another function
  drawChart(result);
}

function drawChart(result) {
  var chart_data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(result);

  var options = {
    title: 'Comments by Group',
    sliceVisibilityThreshold: 1/20,
    width: 400,
    height: 400
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('groupPieChartDiv'));
  chart.draw(chart_data, options);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer.

I cannot get this to work with including data in the callback. drawChart(arrayData); does not work for me...although this could be because of location in my JS.

I stored the graph data in a global variable and then it works - I'll update my question with the current setup...still not sure how document.ready() interacts...

Comment: just to be clear, I'm not able to use your code successfully - passing data through the callback does not work for me.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up...will try it and let you know...

Out of curiosity, what happens if you leave document.ready in there also?

Comment: nothing, it would be fine -- google will take slightly longer, so i wouldn't have anything in the document ready function, that depends on google being loaded...

Comment: That did it! Many thanks WhiteHat - very cool to have been helped by a TVA  engineer:)

Comment: glad to help, anytime -- but I'm actually an accountant! :-0